# Fail when update system

Tags: apt, updates

I get in some trouble when I tried to update the system

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  521  Origin Down [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  521  Origin Down [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to follow some old [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) but it didn't work just because I didn't download from PPA repository but GetDeb.
I tried to follow this [guide](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/14.04#how_to_install) in GetDeb but when I enter `sudo apt-get update`, the terminal still informs about the same error.

Updated with [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1wrpHCCu) the source list

Update with new information when `sudo apt-get update`, this shows a new error:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_trusty-getdeb_apps_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_trusty-getdeb_apps_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_trusty-getdeb_apps_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_trusty-getdeb_apps_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: It seems that server you are trying to reach is down. Could you update your question with `/etc/apt/sources.list` content? If file has many lines, you can use http://pastebin.com/ and post url.

Comment: I updated, you can check again

Comment: Last line is commented out and is different from the one indicated in the [guide](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/14.04#how_to_install), you're using deb-src instead of deb. However, it seems that the server is unavailable. Maybe if you wait and retry it will work.

Comment: It's still not worked, I will try it tomorrow

Comment: It now shows the duplicate, could you please help?

Comment: It means that there are two entries for the same repository. Check where are defined using these commands: `grep "archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps" /etc/apt.list` and `grep "archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` If you find out multiple definition, remove duplicated items and redo `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: For first command : `grep: /etc/apt.list: No such file or directory`
For second command: nothing happens

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake, the command is: grep "archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps" /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 3):

First error:

```
   W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  521  Origin Down [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]
```

means that server is down. I tested repository url and it is really down.

Second error that you got means that there are two entries for the same repository.

Check where are defined using these commands:

```
  grep "archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps" /etc/apt/sources.list 
  grep "archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

If you find out multiple definition, remove duplicated items and redo:

```
  sudo apt-get update
```

Today I checked repository url and now it seems up.